# Asp.Net MVC Property Grid Replacement

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently migrating an old forms application for MVC.  The forms application has a property grid, which automatically binds to an object.  The object has [Category] attributes assigned to each property.  The object is also very complex.

Is it better to build the View for this from scratch or use reflection to generate the UI.  Personally, I prefer to build it using HTML, but the object is very big.  If it is still preferable to build the entire UI using @Html.TextBoxFor(), then that's the way I'll do.

Also, I might end up creating a ViewModel for this, but that's a maybe.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not something we can advise you on.  Reflection is a good tool, but you have to decide whether or not its appropriate for your needs.  We don't know all the details of your app, and without knowing the whole picture, advising you is not going to be very productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends! Do you have many similar objects that can benefit from reflection? Is that code is going to be reused many times over in different views? If yes, do reflection.

Otherwise path down reflection will take you more time to work out. And given that you already have required html, just use it! Keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I kind of decided.  I want to keep everything simple, so went the path of Html.